# Network installer USB drive just starts FreeDOS

Tags: boot, usb, netinstall

I want to install Ubuntu over network with a minimal installation from USB drive.

On https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer I clicked *Download the network installer for 18.04 LTS* and then *amd64*. I was presented with a directory listing, from which I chose *mini.iso*.

Then (I think) I followed this tutorial: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows.
I didn't get the "ISOHybrid image detected" message, though.

When I boot from the resulting USB drive I am presented with four options in the boot menu:

```
UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
P1: WDC WD50000... (the internal HDD)
Kingston Data Traveler
UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler
```

`KingstonDataTraveler` leads to a keyboard selection and then to a FreeDOS command prompt.
`UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler` leads to a "Insert boot media" error message.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found what I did wrong.

After step 5 the *Boot selection* "FreeDOS" from step 4 was lost. I assumed I had accidentally changed it and set it back to "FreeDOS". This was wrong.

It is totally normal that after step 5 the *Boot selection* is the name of the .iso and one should not set it back to "FreeDOS".

I don't quite understand why the tutorial includes step 4 to set *Boot selection* to "FreeDOS" when it will be overwritten immediately.